# Display WordPress Post Content in 3 Columns

Tags: php

How can I display WordPress Post Content in 3 Columns and in order using WP_Query(); ?

For example,

```
<div class="1column">
    Post-1
    Post-4
</div>
<div class="2column">
    Post-2
    Post-5
</div>
<div class="3column">
    Post-3
    Post-6
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query the posts like you are known to it, but then get all posts and restructure them for the order you need it. Take care of setting up the global `$post` variable your own so that to ensure you template code still works.

The [`array_chunk`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_chunk) function normally comes in handy for column based output:

```
$query = WP_Query($queryParameters);
if ($query->have_posts())
{
    $columnCount = 3;
    $rows = array_chunk($query->get_posts(), $columnCount);
    foreach (range(0, $columnCount - 1) as $column)
    {
        printf("<div class=\"class-%dcolumn\">\n", $column + 1);
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            if (false == isset($row[$column]))
            {
                continue;
            }
            $post = $row[$column];
            setup_postdata($post);
?>
   ... single post template html/php mixture ...
<?php            
        }
        print("</div>\n");
    }
}
```

Some additional notes:

- CSS class names can not start with a number. Please see the CSS specification and/or [What characters are valid in CSS class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names) - I prefixed those with `class-...`.
- You might not need this exact source-order. If not, you can just output one post after the other and take care of column display with CSS only. That normally lightens up the template code a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code...

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$get_all_post = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=15&paged=' . $paged);
$post_cont=0;
while ( $get_all_post->have_posts() ) : $get_all_post->the_post();
if(($post_cont)%3==0 || $post_cont==3){?><div class='1column'><?php }?>

title
  content...
<?php if(($post_cont)==2 || $post_cont==5){?></div><?php }?>


$post_cont++;
    endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to make it like this, and in html it is valid, and it indexes better on google:
If you agree this would be better I gladly give the `WP_Query` code if you want it.

```
<style><!--put this in the css-->
.column{
    float:left;
    width:33.3%;
}
</style>
<div class="column">
    Post-1
</div>
<div class="column">
    Post-2
</div>
<div class="column">
    Post-3
</div>
<div class="column">
    Post-4
</div>
<div class="column">
    Post-5
</div>
<div class="column">
    Post-6
</div>
```